# SQL Server 2017 - Recuperar descrição/comentário de coluna na tabela no banco de dados - Metadados

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou tentando gerar um dicionario de dados do meu banco de dados no SQL Server 2017, e gostaria de recuperar a descrição/comentário do campo 'Description' contido nas definições da coluna de cada tabela. Me inspirei em um código que encontrei em um site, mas não estou conseguindo adicionar esse metadado da tabela.

#### Campo desejado:

[image: Campo description]

#### SQL que estou utilizando:

```
SELECT

S.name as 'Schema',

T.name as Tabela,

C.name as Coluna,

TY.name as Tipo,

C.max_length as 'Tamanho Máximo', -- Tamanho em bytes, para nvarchar normalmente se divide este valor por 2

C.precision as 'Precisão', -- Para tipos numeric e decimal (tamanho)

C.scale as 'Escala' -- Para tipos numeric e decimal (números após a virgula)

FROM sys.columns C

INNER JOIN sys.tables T
ON T.object_id = C.object_id

INNER JOIN sys.types TY
ON TY.user_type_id = C.user_type_id

LEFT JOIN sys.schemas S
ON T.schema_id = S.schema_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O *description* da coluna está na tabela **sys.extended_properties**, precisa incluir no seu `select` fazendo o join com object_id, assim:

```
left join sys.extended_properties tep on T.object_id = tep.major_id
```

Usei `left join` caso a coluna não tenha *description*.  Inclua no select a coluna "value":

```
tep.value [Description]
```

Comment: Funcionou !!! Muito obrigado cara, você é fera !!